# linux teradata ODBC SQLConnect Error

Tags: linux, unix, odbc, teradata

I can successfully connect to DB2 using my odbc files. But when I try it with Teradata I get the following error:

```
$ /opt/teradata/client/13.10/odbc_64/samples/C/adhoc
/opt/teradata/client/13.10/odbc_64/samples/C/adhoc: /usr/lib64/libodbc.so: no version information available (required by /opt/teradata/client/13.10/odb  c_64/samples/C/adhoc)

Enter Data Source Name: TDProd
Enter UserID: <username>
Enter Password: *****

Connecting with SQLConnect(DSN=TDProd,UID=walkera,PWD=*)...

adhoc: SQLError() couldn't find text, RC=100

ODBC connection closed.
```

In my odbc.ini file I have the following entries:

```
[ODBC]
InstallDir=/opt/teradata/client/13.10/odbc_64
Trace=0
TraceDll=/opt/teradata/client/13.10/odbc_64/lib/odbctrac.so
TraceFile=/usr/joe/odbcusr/trace.log
TraceAutoStop=0

[ODBC Data Sources]
testdsn=tdata.so

[testdsn]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/13.10/odbc_64/lib/tdata.so
Description=Teradata running Teradata V1R5.2
DBCName=*******
LastUser=
Username=
Password=
Database=
DefaultDatabase=
```

And in my odbcinst.ini file I have this entry for Teradata:

```
[ODBC DRIVERS]
Teradata=Installed

# Example driver definitions

# Driver for Teradata
[Teradata]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/13.10/odbc_64/lib/tdata.so
APILevel=CORE
ConnectFunctions=YYY
DriverODBCVer=3.51
SQLLevel=1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? BTEQ works fine

```
BTEQ 13.10.00.06 Tue Jul 28 17:12:52 2015

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----

.RUN FILE /home/<username>/TDlogin;
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.logmech ldap
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.LOGON ****/<username>,

*** Logon successfully completed.
*** Teradata Database Release is 14.00.04.09
*** Teradata Database Version is 14.00.04.09
*** Transaction Semantics are BTET.
*** Session Character Set Name is 'ASCII'.

*** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
*** Warning: EOF on INPUT stream.
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----

.EXPORT DATA FILE=/home/<username>/output;
*** To reset export, type .EXPORT RESET
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.set RECORDMODE OFF;
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.set separator ","
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.set heading '';
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.set footing '';
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.set titledashes off;
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.set quiet on;
*** Type QUIET OFF; to resume output.
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----


HELP COLUMN ESA_VIEWS.VDDA_FACT.*;
*** Total elapsed time was 2 seconds.


+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----


.EXPORT RESET
*** Output returned to console.
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----

.LOGOFF
*** You are now logged off from the DBC.
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----

.EXIT
*** Exiting BTEQ...
*** RC (return code) = 0
```

Comment: Your odbc.ini file does not have the DSN named TDProd listed, yet your log suggests that SQLConnect is using TDProd as the DSN. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry in I copied from my user dsn file. TDProd has the exact listing as testdsn but is in the system dsn file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when it loads the libodbc.so which is in /usr/lib64 instead of $ODBCHOME/lib directory.

Source: https://network.informatica.com/thread/20115

(in linux)

It worked for me, change the LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that it looks into /opt/teradata/client/XX.XX/lib64 or /opt/teradata/client/XX.XX/lib32

this is needed in your program makefile: -L/opt/teradata/client/15.10/lib64 -lodbc -lodbcinst -lddicuXX